# No audio "No response from codec, resetting bus" KDE Neon

Tags: audio

No audio, I now have a useless output called HDMI / DisplayPort that is barely better than a dummy becaue the audio level is slidable and it seems to detect something when I play music (the color bar moves)
I don't care about HDMI so I don't know what it is. I'm on a laptop so it's likely that I don't even have this.
alsa-info output:

```
name=root&type=33&description=/tmp/alsa-info.txt&expiry=&s=Submit+Post&content=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.5.0
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Wed Apr 21 23:44:29 UTC 2021


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------




!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Product Version:   OEM default string inject
Firmware Version:  HW-13.3-BI-X133GRX210-040-A
System SKU:        1315E20201113001


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------



!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.4.0-72-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       No


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.4.0-72-generic
Library version:    
Utilities version:  1.2.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel (card 0)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1210000 irq 131


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
-ne     
align_buffer_size : -1
-ne     
bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-ne     
beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
-ne     
dmic_detect : N
-ne     
enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
-ne     
enable_msi : -1
-ne     
id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
-ne     
index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-ne     
jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
-ne     
model : generic,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
-ne     
patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
-ne     
pm_blacklist : Y
-ne     
position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-ne     
power_save : 1
-ne     
power_save_controller : Y
-ne     
probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-ne     
probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
-ne     
single_cmd : -1
-ne     
snoop : -1


!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card0
Driver: /sys/bus/pci/drivers/snd_hda_intel
Tree:


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Intel Generic
Address: 2
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x8086280d
Subsystem Id: 0x80860101
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
N/A
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power: setting=UNKNOWN, actual=UNKNOWN, Error, Clock-stop-OK, Setting-reset
Invalid AFG subtree
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Apr 22 01:19 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Apr 22 01:19 /dev/snd/hwC0D2
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Apr 22 01:26 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Apr 22 01:32 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Apr 22 01:19 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Apr 22 01:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 160 Apr 22 01:19 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Apr 22 01:19 pci-0000:00:0e.0 -> ../controlC0


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card PCH

Card hw:0 'PCH'/'HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1210000 irq 131'
  Mixer name    : 'Intel Generic'
  Components    : 'HDA:8086280d,80860101,00100000'
  Controls      : 6
  Simple ctrls  : 1
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
state.PCH {
    control.1 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0482000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write locked'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.4 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.5 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI Jack'
        value true
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.6 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 3
        value.1 4
        comment {
            access read
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
}
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

8250_dw
ac97_bus
acpi_thermal_rel
aesni_intel
af_alg
ahci
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
autofs4
bluetooth
bnep
bpfilter
btbcm
btintel
btrfs
btrtl
btusb
cfg80211
cmac
coretemp
cqhci
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
dm_crypt
drm
drm_kms_helper
dw_dmac
dw_dmac_core
ecc
ecdh_generic
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
hid
hid_generic
hid_multitouch
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_i801
i915
idma64
input_leds
int3400_thermal
int3403_thermal
int340x_thermal_zone
intel_cstate
intel_hid
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_pmc_ipc
intel_powerclamp
intel_punit_ipc
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_soc_dts_iosf
intel_telemetry_core
intel_telemetry_pltdrv
ip6_tables
ip6t_REJECT
ip6t_rt
ip6table_filter
ip_tables
ipt_REJECT
iptable_filter
joydev
kvm
kvm_intel
ledtrig_audio
libahci
libcrc32c
lp
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
mmc_block
msr
nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_log_common
nf_log_ipv4
nf_log_ipv6
nf_reject_ipv4
nf_reject_ipv6
nls_iso8859_1
parport
parport_pc
pinctrl_geminilake
pinctrl_intel
ppdev
processor_thermal_device
raid6_pq
rapl
rfcomm
rtl8821ce
sch_fq_codel
sdhci
sdhci_pci
serio_raw
snd
snd_compress
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_ext_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_sof
snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
soundcore
sparse_keymap
spi_pxa2xx_platform
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
uas
usb_storage
usbhid
uvcvideo
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videodev
virt_dma
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xor
xt_LOG
xt_addrtype
xt_conntrack
xt_hl
xt_limit
xt_tcpudp
zstd_compress


!!Sysfs Files
!!-----------

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/init_pin_configs:
0x03 0x18560010

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/hints:


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    0.224664] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.224666] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.224669] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[   14.786984] Invalid pltconfig, ensure IPC1 device is enabled in BIOS
[   14.804406] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
[   14.812435] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   14.821035] Invalid pltconfig, ensure IPC1 device is enabled in BIOS
--
[   14.838738] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x829a7644
[   14.857848] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   14.857851] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   14.857853] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   14.857854] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   14.857855] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    dig-out=0x3/0x0
[   14.857856] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    inputs:
[   14.859142] mei_hdcp 0000:00:0f.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[   14.861803] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input13
[   15.126602] rtl8821ce 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
--
[   16.346459] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[   18.900515] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x20270503
[   19.908503] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x20270503
[   20.916497] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   21.928750] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   22.940754] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d81
[   23.944737] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   25.992744] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   27.000647] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   27.380115] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[   27.498531] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=2c:d2:6b:cb:f0:ca:60:d2:48:b3:04:5a:08:00 SRC=193.11.166.194 DST=192.168.0.107 LEN=948 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=55783 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27020 DPT=50836 WINDOW=2454 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[   28.012541] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   30.056495] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   31.068532] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   31.209880] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=2c:d2:6b:cb:f0:ca:60:d2:48:b3:04:5a:08:00 SRC=193.11.166.194 DST=192.168.0.107 LEN=948 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=55784 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27020 DPT=50836 WINDOW=2454 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[   32.076533] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   34.129210] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   35.140663] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   36.144511] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   38.184513] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   39.188524] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   39.913318] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=2c:d2:6b:cb:f0:ca:60:d2:48:b3:04:5a:08:00 SRC=193.11.166.194 DST=192.168.0.107 LEN=948 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=55785 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27020 DPT=50836 WINDOW=2454 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[   40.200545] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   42.248535] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   43.252651] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   44.260602] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   46.316535] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   47.334000] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   48.354342] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   50.415951] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   51.433494] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   52.442230] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   54.490381] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   55.505439] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   56.516384] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   58.565010] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   58.645289] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=2c:d2:6b:cb:f0:ca:60:d2:48:b3:04:5a:08:00 SRC=193.11.166.194 DST=192.168.0.107 LEN=948 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=55786 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27020 DPT=50836 WINDOW=2454 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[   59.578667] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   60.588411] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   61.725994] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   62.739216] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   63.748273] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   64.753233] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   65.790163] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   66.802882] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   67.807455] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   68.811885] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   69.848483] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   70.856938] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   71.861248] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   72.865581] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   73.901931] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   74.914091] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   75.922306] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   76.930233] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   77.966672] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   78.974952] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   79.980286] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   80.989644] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   82.026874] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   83.036065] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   84.045184] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   85.058246] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   86.095319] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   87.099972] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   88.108947] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   89.121953] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   90.162794] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   91.171515] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   92.176143] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   93.184957] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   93.489838] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=2c:d2:6b:cb:f0:ca:60:d2:48:b3:04:5a:08:00 SRC=193.11.166.194 DST=192.168.0.107 LEN=948 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=55787 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27020 DPT=50836 WINDOW=2454 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[   94.221415] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   95.230237] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[   96.242677] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   97.251242] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   98.291721] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   99.304238] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  100.316717] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  101.325236] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  102.365670] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370740
[  103.382161] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370740
[  104.386514] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d81
[  104.386524] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -11
[  105.390896] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d81
[  105.390908] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -11
[  106.403278] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x203f0900
[  107.407677] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x202a0000
[  109.440366] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x20270503
[  109.440537] azx_single_wait_for_response: 9 callbacks suppressed
[  110.004966] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  110.005104] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  110.192683] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
--
[  446.659740] azx_single_wait_for_response: 32 callbacks suppressed
[  446.938973] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  446.939145] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  513.120565] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:60:d2:48:b3:04:5a:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=7681 PROTO=2 


!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-topology-conf                            1.2.2-1                                      all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.6                             all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                    1.2.2-1ubuntu2                               amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```